# example of an NL-completeness reduction?

Tags: reductions, space-complexity, polynomial-time-reductions, 2-sat

I'm looking for simple examples of nondeterministic log-space completeness reductions. In particular I seem unable to construct any nontrivial widget using 2-SAT clauses, which is known to be NL-complete.

Comment: Figure 1 [here](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2004/100/) provides some examples of CSPs which are NP-complete.